# Adding a class to custom TinyMCE button using WPLinks dialog box

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I'm trying to achieve a custom button within the WordPress editor that a user can click to insert and the link is added, already styled with the relevant classes.

I've added a custom button to TinyMCE in WordPress and loaded the WpLink dialogue box for adding links to the editor.

So far so good however I'm having trouble editing the output of the form submission to add a class for styling the link as a button.

Any assistance would be great as the documentation is terrible.

```
(function() {
  tinymce.PluginManager.add('demo_styles', function( editor, url ) {
    editor.addButton( 'demo_styles', {
      text: '',
      image: '../wp-content/themes/demo/dist/assets/images/icons/mce/demo.svg);',
      type: 'menubutton',
      menu: [
        {
          text: 'Item 1',
          menu: [
            {
              text: 'Hollow Button',
              onclick: function() {
                wpLink.open(
                );
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });
  });
})();
```

Comment: I have a little beginning of help. you can catch the event which create the link with this code : `var editor = tinymce["editors"][0]; editor.on("ExecCommand", function (e) { console.log(editeur); });` but after that I don't have found how to modify the selected link.

Comment: Thanks, it's a start but I'm still unsure how to edit the output in the editor when a link is inserted.